# Can I use WebCompiler to compile SASS files using Github Actions with ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, sass, web-compiler

I've got an ASPNET Core 3.1 MVC web application. I've added a .SCSS file to the project, and installed the [WebCompiler](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler) Visual Studio extension to compile the SCSS files when I build the project. I've enabled the custom build steps so that running `dotnet build` will run the WebCompiler and generate the `.css` output files.

I'm now trying to automate this via Github Actions, and WebCompiler is failing during the build:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 5.66 sec for /home/runner/work/ndc-expo/ndc-expo/project.csproj.

  WebCompiler: Begin compiling compilerconfig.json
  WebCompiler installing updated versions of the compilers...
/home/runner/.nuget/packages/buildwebcompiler/1.12.394/build/BuildWebCompiler.targets(12,9):
   error : No such file or directory [/home/runner/work/ndc-expo/ndc-expo/project.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/home/runner/.nuget/packages/buildwebcompiler/1.12.394/build/BuildWebCompiler.targets(12,9):
  error : No such file or directory [/home/runner/work/ndc-expo/ndc-expo/project.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:07.57
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Trying to replicate the build locally (Ubuntu 20.04 with dotnet sdk 3.1) gives the same error - so I'm guessing that WebCompiler just plain doesn't work on Linux... anybody know a way to enable or work around this? All the project docs say is that it has "MSBuild support for CI scenarios" - no explicit statement on whether I should expect it to work with Linux or not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to change to this [WebCompiler](https://github.com/excubo-ag/WebCompiler) as dotnet tool to compiler sass files. You can use it then with Github Actions like this:

```
- name: Install WebCompiler
        run: dotnet tool install Excubo.WebCompiler --global
        
- name: Run WebCompiler
        run: webcompiler //your_params_here
```

This tool is currently supported by authors, not like the madskristensen WebCompiler and supports newest sass syntax.